# dygraphs: Dealing with millions of points

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

The front page of the Dygraph's site claims it can easily handle plots of millions of points, however, I have not had this be the case.
I am loading an array of 1 million X,Y values and though it displays the graph after a short delay it is unable to be interacted with.

How can I best setup Dygraphs to handle this large amount of data?

Here are my setup options:

```
drawPoints: false,
showRoller: false,
rollPeriod: 1,
animatedZooms: false,
panEdgeFraction: 0,
axes: {
    x: {
        drawAxis: false
    }
},
showRangeSelector: true,
rangeSelectorPlotFillColor: '',
rangeSelectorHeight: 80,
valueRange: [0, 65535],
labels: ['Time', 'Level']
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Can you share a link to the chart that's running slowly?

Comment: @danvk You can try it here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJmGmd -- It is loading 10MB of JSON over AJAX. It's not ridiculously slow. But I wish the chart would draw faster and the first few levels of zooming would be faster, the zooms are plenty fast once you get closer in. The range selector however is unusable, though we could live without it. If we could just get those first few zooms faster.

Answer (score 2):

The truth is that even in 2019 plotting more than (or even about) one million points is just not doable in a Web browser. Partly due to browsers' performance, partly by design due to the client-server architecture. The key, which requires some extra work, is to aggregate server-side.

Here is a wonderful article about plotting 50 million points with D3 and a live example: https://int21.io/post/50-million-points/index.html (the TL;DR is "you don’t.. at least, not all at the same time"); and here are live examples of the same concept with Dygraphs: https://github.com/kaliatech/dygraphs-dynamiczooming-example.

2024 Update: Link to the article is gone, such a pity. Have a look here for the original text, but the dynamic zooming example is gone: https://web.archive.org/web/20210621134949/https://int21.io/post/50-million-points/index.html.